# unclear circular dependency with FeignClient and Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

My springboot app was working fine untill I added the following class:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AutoopsClientPostBootListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>
{
    private final IAutoOpsGnsFlowInitiator gnsFlowInitator;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event)
    {
      gnsFlowInitator.startClient(event);
    }
}
```

For some odd reason after that, I get a circular dependency error stemming from 
**feign client** dependent on **AutoopsClientPostBootListener** from above.

It happens becasue IAutoOpsGnsFlowInitiator is dependent on the feign client which depend on AutoopsClientPostBootListener. But FeignClient doesn't even have any members.. (feign auto generates it) so how can it be dependent on the Listener?!!

whats the problem??

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

So the problem was with ApplicationListener(no idea why).
Using @EventListener solved the problem.

```
@EventListener
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event)
    {
      gnsFlowInitator.startClient(event);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I couldn't find any explanation in the documentation why this happens. The combination of an `@Auwowired` `@FeignClient` and `implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` results in a circular dependency error although there is no such dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The issue depends on the phase of your context, once your context is initialized or changes there is a call on refresh, so you event will be fired, if you need to execute your startClient once your context is fully initialized then you `@EventListener` will be trigger with `ContextStartedEvent` which is only called once your application context was fully initialized so feign is already loaded.

Hopefully this can be helpful.